# C++, Net, WindowsForms Sorting list by values of other list

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

I have two lists. One has type of MyClass and is filled with these classes wrote by me. And the second one has some int values.

And the problem is that I don't know how to deal with sorting the first list using values of the second one.
I have no idea how to write an IComparer to use sort list method. I saw an example in msdn but I don't know how to change it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx#Y535

Here's my program:

//##################################

```
ref class MyClass{
private:
  int x;
  int y;
  String^ name;
public:
  MyClass(int x, int y, String^ name){
  this->x = x;
  this->y = y;
  this->name = name;
}
...
};

//###### in some button which will initialize...:

List<MyClass^>^ listMyClass = gcnew List<MyClass^>(3);
listMyClass->Add(gcnew MyClass(3, 5, "class1"));
listMyClass->Add(gcnew MyClass(1, 2, "class2"));
listMyClass->Add(gcnew MyClass(6, 8, "class3"));

List<int>^ numbers = gcnew List<int>(3);
numbers->Add(2);
numbers->Add(4);
numbers->Add(1);
```

//###################################

These numbers of numbers List represent some kind of a status of elements of listMyClass. So I'd like to sort listMyClass using values form the list numbers.
I would like to have such result after sorting:
`listMyClass[1]` is first because number 4 from the list numbers is the highest. Then
`listMyClass[0]` and then `listMyClass[2]`

Are there any posibilities to deal with this challange?

Answer (score 0):

If are unique `int values` in second list, you may use a `std::vector` for inserting `MyClass`in the position indicated by int values you stored un second list. If not, use a `std::multiset` with `int values` as key.

Answer (score 0):

*(not specific to C++/CLI)*

Use `Dictionary<int, int>` in place of the second list:

- Key is the status.
- Value is the **sort order** of that status.

You can then easily implement a custom `IComparer<T>.Compare(T x, T y)` that would...

1. Lookup the sort order of the `x.status` from the `Dictionary`.
2. Lookup the sort order of the `y.status` from the `Dictionary`.
3. Compare these sort orders directly.

...then pass this comparer to `List<T>.Sort(IComparer<T>)` for the first list.

P.S. For a native C++ solution, you could use a similar idea with `std::unordered_map<int, int>`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to defeat this challange :)
Here's the solution

```
ref class MyClass:IComparable<MyClass^>{
public:
  int x;
  int y;
  int status;
  String^ name;

  MyClass(int x, int y, String^ name){
  this->x = x;
  this->y = y;
  this->name = name;
  }

  virtual int CompareTo(MyClass^ tmpMyClass){
      if(this->status > tmpMyClass->status)
         return 1;
      if(this->status < tmpMyClass->status)
         return -1;
      else
         return 0;
  }
...
};

//###### in some button which will initialize...:

List<MyClass^>^ listMyClass = gcnew List<MyClass^>(3);
listMyClass->Add(gcnew MyClass(3, 5, "class1"));
listMyClass->Add(gcnew MyClass(1, 2, "class2"));
listMyClass->Add(gcnew MyClass(6, 8, "class3"));

List<int>^ numbers = gcnew List<int>(3);
numbers->Add(2);
numbers->Add(4);
numbers->Add(1);

for(int i=0; i<listMyClass->Count; i++){
   listMyClass->status = numbers[i];
}
listMyClass->Sort();
```

I felt such relief :) Thank You for any advices.